# How to select columns in data.table using a character vector of certain column names?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to select those columns in a data.table whose name appears in my character vector. The operation works in a pure data.frame, but doesn't work in a data.table. Here's a reproducible example.

```
> names(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
[11] "carb"
> myVector <- c('disp', 'hp', 'wt')
> head(mtcars[, myVector])
                  disp  hp    wt
Mazda RX4          160 110 2.620
Mazda RX4 Wag      160 110 2.875
Datsun 710         108  93 2.320
Hornet 4 Drive     258 110 3.215
Hornet Sportabout  360 175 3.440
Valiant            225 105 3.460
```

I just made a vector which includes `disp`, `hp`, and `wt` and I selected the corresponding columns in my data.frame using that vector. Let's now make a data.table object from my data.frame and try to do the same operation.

```
> library(data.table)
> mtcarsDT <- data.table(mtcars)
> mtcarsDT[, myVector]
[1] "disp" "hp"   "wt"
```

Comment: You can use: mtcarsDT[, myVector, with =FALSE]

Answer (score 103, accepted):

We can use `..` notation to find `myVector` as a vector of column positions, like it would work in `data.frame`

```
mtcarsDT[, ..myVector]
```

According to `?data.table`

> In case of overlapping variables names inside dataset and in parent scope you can use double dot prefix `..cols` to explicitly refer to 'cols variable parent scope and not from your dataset.

Comment: This doesn't work if myvector contains names that are not in the data.table

Comment: @HermanToothrot You may need `intersect` if that is the case

Comment: For anyone developing packages and wanting to avoid issues with devtools::check, use the older functionality of `dt[, myVector, with=FALSE]`

Comment: @akrun can you provide an example?

Comment: @HermanToothrot in the dupe links, there are examples.  Can you click on those