# non-numeric argument to mathematical function error in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table object with the following column.
Doing an exp on one of the columns results in an error as shown below:

```
  data <-  data.table('Speed' = c(90, 95, 100, 30, 49, 45, 10, 82),
                      'Fuel' = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.15, 5, 3, 4, 2))

speed_var='Speed'

exp(data[,c(speed_var)])
```

Error message is

```
non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Strangely doing `exp(data[,'Speed'])` is working but if I put the column name in a variable and access, I am getting this error. Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Not about the problem itself, but you're missing a closing `)`. I don't know data.table well, but it seems related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32184252/5325862) and the posts linking to it. Take a look at what you get with `data[,c(speed_var)]`: it's the name of the selected column, not the column itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the column as a vector with `[[`

```
exp(data[[speed_var]])
```

---

Or another option if we need it as a `data.table`

```
exp(data[, ..speed_var])
```

Or specify the column in `.SDcols` and apply the `exp` on .SD`

```
data[, exp(.SD), .SDcols = speed_var]
```